# php and javascript to iweb

Tags: php, iweb

I am newbie in web development, We have designed a basic HTML webpages using iweb(mac software), I would like to know whether it's a flexible to add PHP and Javascript to the these pages, or it's designed only for simple HTML pages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably *could*, but as far as I know, iWeb is like the Frontpage of Mac? I have never really opened it on my Macbook, to be honest.

If you really want to get into web development, I suggest you stay away from editors like iWeb, Frontpage, even Dreamweaver (my personal opinion).

I would advise you to pick up some books or follow [some basic tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/web-design-from-scratch/) and work with a decent IDE (Aptana, ..) or code editor (I'm thinking Textmate, Coda, ...).

[This NetTuts screencast](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/web-design-from-scratch-choosing-an-editor/) is entirely dedicated to choosing an editor. Perhaps that helps you!

Edit: Since you're new to webdesign, and I ran into another question regarding 'being new' a couple of minutes ago, I'm also going to tell you the same as I told the other person: stay away from [w3schools](http://w3fools.com/). It's evil.